# Sorting Table Data into Quintiles/Deciles

Tags: python

I'm struggling to sort my data table into quintiles/deciles etc.  I'm just using some state data to practice since I'm new and learning.  Here is my code so far.

```
state_data = {
    "name":['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'DC', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahmoa', 'Oregon', 'Pennslyvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'],
    "pop millions": [4.8, 0.7, 7.0, 3.0, 39.5, 5.6, 3.6, 1.0, 0.7, 21.0, 10.4, 1.4, 1.7, 12.8, 6.7, 3.1, 2.9, 4.4, 4.6, 1.3, 6.1, 6.9, 9.9, 5.6, 3.0, 6.1, 1.1, 1.9, 3.0, 1.3, 9.0, 2.1, 19.8, 10.2, 0.7, 11.6, 3.9, 4.1, 12.8, 1.1, 5.0,0.9, 6.7, 28.3, 3.1, 0.6, 8.5, 7.4, 1.8, 5.8, 0.6],
    "% White":[66, 61, 55, 72, 37, 68, 67, 62, 37, 54, 53, 22, 82, 61, 80, 86, 76, 85, 59, 93, 51, 72, 75, 80, 57, 79, 86, 79, 49, 90, 55, 37, 55, 63, 84, 79, 66, 76, 76, 72, 64, 82, 74, 42, 78, 93, 62, 69, 92, 81, 84],
    '2016 Clinton Vote Share':[35, 38, 45, 34, 62, 47, 55, 53, 93, 48, 46, 62, 28, 55, 38, 42, 36, 32, 38, 48, 61, 61, 47, 47, 40, 38, 36, 34, 48, 48, 55, 48, 59, 47, 28, 44, 29, 52, 48, 55, 41, 32, 35, 43, 28, 62, 50, 54, 27, 47, 23],
    'Homicide Rate per 100k':[8.3, 8.4, 5.9, 8.6, 4.6, 3.9, 2.8, 5.6, 23, 5, 6.7, 2.7, 1.9, 7.8, 6, 3.3, 5.5, 5.9, 12.4, 1.7, 9, 2.5, 5.7, 2, 8.2, 9.8, 3.9, 2.2, 9.1, 1, 3.6, 7.1, 2.8, 5.8, 1.3, 6.1, 6.2, 2.5, 5.8, 1.9, 7.8, 2.9, 7.8, 5, 2.4, 2.2, 5.3, 3.1, 4.7, 3.2, 2.6],
    'Police Shootings 2019':[104, 39, 253, 82, 798, 195, 21, 13, 13, 350, 182, 30, 42, 103, 95, 32, 49, 95, 109, 22, 79, 35, 78, 61, 65, 139, 31, 24, 96, 13, 68, 106, 101, 156, 11, 155, 164, 88, 108, 4, 88, 17, 139, 480, 60, 9, 95, 152, 54, 91, 14]
  }


table['police_shootings_per_million'] = table['Police Shootings 2019'] / table['pop millions']
print(table)

plt.scatter(table["% White"],table["police_shootings_per_million"])

plt.ylabel("Police Shootings per Million People")
plt.xlabel("% White")
plt.title("Police Shootings and Race")

m, b = np.polyfit(table["% White"],table["police_shootings_per_million"], 1)
plt.plot(table["% White"], m * table["% White"] + b, color = "green")

plt.show()
```

.....again I'm just practicing doing a bunch of stuff.  But I tried finding quintiles with this code.

table[police_shootings_per_million].quantile(0.2)

I got this error.

NameError: name 'table' is not defined

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance and I'll make sure to mark the correct answer.

Comment: Where in your code are you defining 'table'? I don't see `table = ...` anywhere in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with numpy or percentiles or any stats; you’ve just not declared any variable table in the above code.

You create a dictionary called state data.

You then try to assign a value to key “ police_shootings_per_million” of a variable `table`.

But, there is no table.

Given that you’re trying to divide the values from two other keys, I assume you expect `table` to be a pandas dataframe? A dataframe would also be a perfect data structure to do your percentile analysis from.

If so, you’ll want to `import pandas` at the top of the code, and then `table = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(state_data)` after you declare the state_data.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html for more on how to convert the state_data dictionary into a pandas dataframe.